# How to copy the one QImage into another QImage?

Tags: qt

How to copy one QImage into another QImage?
I do not  want to change the size of image

QImage src=function_name();
QImage dst;

Comment: What about `QImage::copy()` function? It creates a copy of the given image.

Comment: please explain with example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `QImage::copy()` function. For example:

```
QImage src = function_name();
QImage dst = src.copy();
```